# Are there private keys in dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have an array. I'm using `Tornado` for WebSockets and I'm using `json`.

```
servers = {
    'server1': {
         'id1': {
             'message': 'msg from id1',
             'message2': 'msg2 from id1'
             'conn': "(here's Tornado WebSocket class - WebSocket connection)"
         },
         'id2': {
              ...
         }
    },
    'server2': {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to send `json.dumps(servers['server1'])` to every user but I don't want to send it with `conn` key. Is there something like private (hidden) keys? I want to do `json.dumps(servers['server1'])` and the output I want is:

```
'id1': {
    'message': 'msg from id1',
    'message2': 'msg2 from id1'
},
...
```

Comment: No, you will have to create a dictionary excluding the key, then dump that via JSON.

Comment: There's no private *anything* in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can emulate them with non-string keys:

```
conn_key = object()  # sentinel value

servers = {
    'server1': {
         'id1': {
             'message': 'msg from id1',
             'message2': 'msg2 from id1'
             conn_key: "(here's Tornado WebSocket class - WebSocket connection)"
         },
         'id2': {
              ...
         }
    },
    'server2': {
        ...
    }
}

print servers['server1']['id1'][conn_key]

json.dumps(servers, skipkeys=True)
```

Comment: see: json.dumps({'test':json,'abc':123},skipkeys=True)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no private or public notions in python. You can use a nested comprehension:

```
message = {id_key:{k:data for k,data in id_val.items() if k != 'conn'} 
    for id_key,id_val in servers['server1'].items()}
```

Comment: the key of servers['server1'] will be id1, id2 not conn! conn is the key of `servers['server1']['id1']`